# In SQL Server, how can I compare a part of a string?

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, select

I have a column where strings are entered in this format:

```
2014-11-30 00:00:00
```

As you can see, this column is a date / time. I want to retrieve all records where the month = 11.

I am hoping to do something like this:

```
select * from table where datetime like XXXX-11-XX XX;XX;XX
```

(where X is literally any value).

Is this possible? If so, how can I achieve it?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type) - you should always use the most appropriate data type - that's what they're there for, after all! If you have a date - ***why*** is that stored as a string column??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [**`Month`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms187813.aspx) Function which Returns an `integer` that represents the `month` of the `specified date`.

```
select * from Table Where Month(datetime) =11
```

Or use [**`DatePart`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms174420.aspx) to extract the `month` from `specified date`

```
SELECT * FROM Table Where DATEPART(MONTH, DateTime) = 11
```

Answer (score 2):

Use **[`DatePart`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms174420.aspx)**

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE DATEPART(MONTH, DateTime) = 11
```